# Can't change value of box storing color in real-time

Tags: java, json, websocket, esp8266

I have a problem with the project on ESP8266. I use a color sensor that collects RGB values and sends them via WebSockets to a server created on ESP, the values pass normally and display on the website in real time. I also wanted to add functionality so that the resulting color appears in the color box. Unfortunately, I can't get this, I have searched all I could.
[This is how it looks, this olive-green color is permanently assigned rgb(120, 120, 0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGMvi.png)

This is code I use for this:

```
websock.onmessage=function(event)
        {
          var obj = JSON.parse(event.data);
                    
          document.getElementById('Rvalue').innerHTML = obj.Rvalue;
          document.getElementById('Gvalue').innerHTML = obj.Gvalue;
          document.getElementById('Bvalue').innerHTML = obj.Bvalue;

          const root = document.documentElement;
          root.style.setProperty('--box-color', '120, 120, 0');
        }
      }

      window.onload = function(event)
      {
        InitWebSocket();
      }
```

I want to change this line: root.style.setProperty('--box-color', '120, 120, 0'); to look like this and work if it is possible.
root.style.setProperty('--box-color', 'Rvalue, Bvalue, Gvalue');

I also used this code to send data to server via WebSocket. Now I have random values, but later I want to attach it to the sensor.

```
unsigned long now = millis();
  if ((unsigned long)(now - previousMillis) > interval) 
  { 
    String jsonString = "";
    StaticJsonDocument<200> doc;
    JsonObject object = doc.to<JsonObject>();
    object["Rvalue"] = random(100);
    object["Gvalue"] = random(100);
    object["Bvalue"] = random(100);
    serializeJson(doc, jsonString);
    Serial.println(jsonString);
    webSocket.broadcastTXT(jsonString);
    
    previousMillis = now;
  }
```

I thought it was a problem with the fact that RGB values are string not INT.

I tried to convert string into INT values in different ways, e.g.:
int Rvalue_int = Integer.valueOf((String) "Rvalue");
or
int Rvalue_int = jsonObj.get("Rvalue").asInt(); but this blocks sending RGB values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the --box-color property value using the received RGB values from the WebSocket message. Change the line:

```
root.style.setProperty('--box-color', '120, 120, 0');
```

to:

```
root.style.setProperty('--box-color', `${obj.Rvalue}, ${obj.Gvalue}, ${obj.Bvalue}`);
```

This will set the --box-color property to the received RGB values in the format 'Rvalue, Gvalue, Bvalue'.

For more information on setting CSS variables using JavaScript, refer to this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty